# How can I add a composer.json to a static TYPO3 project?

Tags: typo3, composer-php

I am using a working TYPO3 7.6.14 environment with many extensions. Now I want to add a composer.json file manually. I do not want to create a new project which will download the latest TYPO3 core and TYPO3 extensions. I am afraid that this could accidently overwrite some extension's PHP files.
I need a safe way to add a composer.json file which will not change the present TYPO3 PHP files automatically. I prefer to download TYPO3 and the extensions manually. Therefore I do not want to use the composer mode. I must find a way to prevent composer from overwriting my self written PHP files.

I need a composer.json file because I want to add the external TCPDF library which is on its own place on the file system and not inside of a vendor folder inside of TYPO3. And the file ext_autoload.php is not supported any more by TYPO3 7.6.

I have read the https://usetypo3.com/typo3-and-composer.html#c51 recommendations. But it only shows the way how to create a new TYPO3 project using the command line and the composer command. Is it also possible to download a composer.json file into a TYPO3 folder (which?) in order to tell the autoloader where it will find the external TCPDF library?
I have unzipped the TCPDF file under /var/www/html/TCPDF-master/tcpdf.php . I want to use TCPDF, TYPO3 and its extensions unchanged and never updated by any composer command.

Answer (score 2):

Introducing Composer for not using it's features seems a bit strange to me, but yes, it's possible to define a dedicated version or commit-hash in a repository to disable updates.

However, I would recommend to make use of the tilde `~` operator to enable updates on the accordant branch, to e.g. include security updates automatically. For TYPO3 CMS this dependency would look like the following, to stay on the 7.6 branch:

```
"require": {
  "typo3/cms": "~7.6.14"
}
```

Find further details on how to declare versions in the [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md).

Besides that, it seems, that you're not using Composer at all for the root project. You could then create a wrapper extension for TCPDF with one of these options:

1. use Composer for that extension to [require TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/composer.json) and load the generated autoload file (e.g. in `typo3conf/ext/tcpdf/vendor/autoload.php`) in your wrapper extension
2. directly copy & paste TCPDF's source (which seems to be the scenario you're up to) and add the autoloading information to `ext_emconf.php`, which is similar to previous `ext_autoload.php` - find details about that in a [blog post about class loading](http://insight.helhum.io/post/130876393595/how-to-configure-class-loading-for-extensions-in)